# Read value from html menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I read the selected value of this menu, as if it were a dropdown list?

For a regular dropdown list like below, I use something like this to read the value:

```
<select id="ddl">
<option value="In" selected="selected">In</option>
<option value="Out">Out</option>
<option value="Ratio">Ratio</option>
</select>
```

With javascript I read the selected value:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("ddl");
var InOrOut = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

Is it possible to use something like this to read the selected value of the menu below:

```js
function FillAll()
{
    alert('I will read value');
    // This is where menu value is read.
    alert('Value read is');
}
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden; /* will contain if #first is longer than #second */
}
#first {
    width: 400px;
    float:left; /* add this */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#second {
    border: 1px solid green;
 text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden; /* if you don't want #second to wrap below #first */
}

.bs-example{
 margin: 20px;
}
.text
{
 font-size: 15pt;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 color: #3d718b;
}
hr{
 margin: 60px 0;
}
</style>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div style="float:left;">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="text" class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" >Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="">Value1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Value2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Value3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    </li>
   </ul> 
  </div>
        <button id="ButtonSearch" onclick="FillAll()">GO</button>
```

Since one can't do much to change the design of the regular dropdown list, I was thinking of using another approach, and use an html menu instead of the ddl.

Something I didn't mention is that the code to read the value would go inside the click event of a button that already exists. I didn't mention it before because I didn't know the click event would be used to read the value.

Comment: How would you know what is selected?

Comment: When do you want to know the selected value?  Because if you want to know upon select, then you can bind a click handler to the options.  If you want to know "later", you could still bind a click handler on the to the options and manage a "selected" class on them, or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getAttribute` to scrape a `value` off of each `li`:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li').click( e => {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('value'));
});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden; /* will contain if #first is longer than #second */
}
#first {
    width: 400px;
    float:left; /* add this */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#second {
    border: 1px solid green;
 text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden; /* if you don't want #second to wrap below #first */
}

.bs-example{
 margin: 20px;
}
.text
{
 font-size: 15pt;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 color: #3d718b;
}
hr{
 margin: 60px 0;
}
</style>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div style="float:left;">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="text" class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" >Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li value="1">Value1</li>
      <li value="2">Value2</li>
      <li value="3">Value3</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    </li>
   </ul> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to do what you need using either jQuery or native JS.

```
 <script>
  // with jquery
 $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(el) {
  console.log(el.target.textContent)
 })

 // native
 const list = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu li');
 list.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function listClick() {
   console.log(el.textContent);
 }));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, yes. The following code, following your example, uses an event handler which is triggered when one of the menu items are clicked. I've also included a working jsfiddle example below.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="text" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" >Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Value 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Value 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Value 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="col-xs-12 text-danger" id="result"></div>
```

**Javascript / jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
    var r = $('#result');
  r.empty().append('You have clicked <strong>'+$(this).text()+'</strong> in the drop-down menu.');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Xonos/z9jfa86r/

---

**UPDATE**: I have added another answer which shows a secondary example where you can select/de-select a menu item and then click a button to determine which of the menu items are selected. The JSFiddle link is below.

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="text" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" >Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Value 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Value 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Value 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 text-red" id="result">&nbsp;</div>
<br>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <button id="checkBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right">Check Selected Menu Item</button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 text-orange" id="check">&nbsp;</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.text-red {
  color:rgb(206, 35, 35);
}
.text-orange {
  color:rgb(252, 144, 0);
}

.nav {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}

.selected-item {
  background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

**Javascript** / **jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '#myDropdown li a', function() {
    var r = $('#result');
  $(this).parent().parent().children().removeClass('selected-item');
  if($(this).hasClass('selected-item')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected-item'); //De-select menu item.
  } else {
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected-item'); //Select menu item.
  }
  r.empty().append('You have selected <strong>'+$(this).text()+'</strong> in the drop-down menu.');
});

$(document).on('click', '#checkBtn', function() {
    var selected = $('#myDropdown .selected-item');
  if(selected.length > 0) { //If any of the menu items <li> have the "selected-item" class added.
    $('#check').empty().append('Found a selected menu item. The value of it is: <strong>'+selected.text()+'</strong>');
  } else {
    $('#check').empty().append('You have not selected an item from the menu.');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Xonos/74pwyL1m/

Comment: Thanks for the post. Would it be possible to add that code without using the `click` event?

Comment: I already have a button with javascript code that runs when it's clicked. It possible, I would need to read the value within the javascript function that does also does other stuff when the click is made.

Comment: Yes. I'll edit my answer to give you more information on this. Mark it as answered if I get it right according to what you want to know.